# Где хранить данные в Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Задумка была импортировать компонент, имеющий только `export default`, без `<template>`. Но как и ожидалось, выдало ошибку. Подскажите, где хранить данные, не поступающие с бд, пока что, они в папке с проектом лежат постоянно.

```js
data() {
    return {
      products: [{
          name: "Hoodie",
          index: 1,
          sale: "17,57$",
          src: require('@/assets/images_products/Hoodies/Hoodie_4.jpg')
        },
        {
          name: "Hoodie",
          index: 2,
          sale: "17,57$",
          src: require('@/assets/images_products/jeans/Jeans_1.jpg')
        },
        {
          name: "Hoodie",
          index: 3,
          sale: "17,57$",
          src: require('@/assets/images_products/T-shirt/Tshirt_4.jpg')
        },
        {
          name: "Hoodie",
          index: 4,
          sale: "17,57$",
          src: require('@/assets/images_products/T-shirt/Tshirt_1.jpg')
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Какие данные? Может вам помогут миксины? Или `Vuex`?

Comment: Я поправил код выше

Comment: Ну создайте файл где-нибудь data.js и подтягивайте константу. `export const data = {...}` и `import { 
data } from 'data.js'` (что-то вроде того)

Comment: Вы хотите хранить изображения?

Comment: Можно сохранить данные в файл json и после простым импортом в нужный компонент обращаться к данным в нем

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть данные, то когда-нибудь они будут идти из апишки с сервака, так что положите сразу в vuex и потом переделывать не придется.

```
state: {
  products: [/* ваши данные */]
},
getters: {
  getProducts: (state) => (state.products),
},
```

А в компонентах где вам нужны ваши продукты вешаете

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getProducts',
    ])
  }
};
```

Все, у вас в компоненте есть переменная getProducts.
В геттерах можно (и даже нужно) описать всякие сортировки и потом дёргать в mapGetters уже их и выводить товары в разделах "Горячее предложение" и т.п.